# Is There a Golang way to create Kind Cluster

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, kind

In Python we can create a kind cluster by

```
from pytest_kind import KindCluster

cluster = KindCluster("myclustername")
cluster.create()
cluster.kubectl("apply", "-f", "..")
# ...
cluster.delete()
```

reference : https://pypi.org/project/pytest-kind/
is there a golang way to create Kind cluster ?

Comment: That library just works by using the `subprocess` library to run the `kind` CLI tool, downloading it first if need be.  You don't say what your application does or why you'd provision infrastructure in a unit test, but one piece I might look at is the [EnvTest module that's part of Kubebuilder](https://kubebuilder.io/reference/envtest), which can start up a local API server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, you are looking for kubernetes-sigs/e2e-framework.

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/e2e-framework

Comment: will try this out